# Check username of print job on network printer

Tags: c#, printing, snmp

I am using `SNMPSharpNet` to receive traps from a network printer to check what kind of job it is (i.e. print, copy, scan, etc.). I would like to be able to get the `username` of the person who sent each print job to the network printer, but this is only done through a `callback` to the printer from what I have read.

- How does one go about receiving additional information about a print job through a network printer?

#### I am connecting to the printer in the application through a socket like so:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

string myIP;
IPEndPoint end;
EndPoint ep;
try
{
    myIP = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[3].ToString();
    end = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(myIP), 162);
    ep = (EndPoint)end;
    socket.Bind(ep);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
}
```

The OID I receive for each job gives me the status of the print job, what type of print job it is, and the job number if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to use SNMP Walk using GetNext or GetBulk to receive the usernames in the printer associated with the print jobs sent to it. The OID used on the walk differs depending on the printer being used and the MIB associated with it. For example:

> I am using a Xerox printer and the OID used for the walk to receive usernames is:
>     1.3.6.1.4.1.253.8.51.5.1.1.4
>
> This only works for Xerox printers since the 253 is a Xerox associated path